# Reputation on post's revisions page may have "k" or "m"

Tags: feature-request, reputation, revisions-list

The reputation on the post's revisions page doesn't not have a thousand ("k") or million ("m").

> [image: No "k"]

Usually on the post or Users page, the user's reputation with the "k" or "m". Adding the "k" or "m" with the reputation will improve the readability.

> [image: Has "k"]

Can this be applied to the revisions page too.